# Nuxt 3 how to change the path of the static build

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

after i build the project

```
npm run generate
```

it generates a folder ***.output*** with the build files

how to change this file to anther, for example instead of ***.output*** -> ***Admin***

my nuxt.config.ts

```
  export default defineNuxtConfig({ 
    ssr: false, 
    app: {
        baseURL: ...,
    },
 });
```

I know that i can cut and past the folder,

however, is there a propriety that can change the path of the build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nuxt3 server engine is actually powered by nitro (see [the document](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/introduction#server-engine))

so, in the `nuxt.config.[js|ts]`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    nitro: {
        output: {
            dir: '.output',
            serverDir: '.output/server',
            publicDir: '.output/public'
        }
    }
})
```

See more:

- [Nitro `output`](https://nitro.unjs.io/config/#output)
- [nuxt-config nitro](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#nitro)